# Can We Get Class Name of Generic Control like UL and LI From The Code Side In asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to find the Class name of li from the Code side I read So many answers related to  my  question but I am still not satisfied

My code in aspx page

```
<ul runat="server"> 

<li class="a">  </li> 

</ul>
```

I want to know Class name of li tag
I have no idea what to do so please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
// read class
string cssClass = myUL.Attributes["class"];
// assign new
myUL.Attributes["class"] = "myCssClass";
```

Comment: TY   for answer..  From    your   answer    i   get   class    name    of    Ul   i want   to   get   class   name    of   li   tag  ..